# Using PYQT with wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, pyqt

I hope this is not an obvious question.  However, I cant find any resources online, since everytime i google wordpress with pyqt, i get websites made with wordpress talking about pyqt.

Are there are resources or tutorials on integrating pyqt with wordpress.  Or is this too vague, and it should be pyqt with mysql?  Or is this just a bad way to write a program in python that gets data from a mysql database?

Comment: If you're asking what I think you're asking, then I'd advise you to use the Python's `mysqldb` module to manipulate the database. The other alternative is `QtSql` which lives in PyQt.

Comment: yes i think you understand my question. could you put it as an answer and explain why for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding what you're looking for here is not to integrate PyQt with WordPress, but rather Python itself. PyQt it simply a toolkit that offers the GUI (and many more) module that you're likely using, but Python is still the "backbone" of your application.

In order to manipulate the database that WordPress uses, you'd have to manipulate that very database. For that, I recommend [MySQLdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5) Python module. Alternatively, you could use the QtSql that PyQt comes with, but I honestly don't see the need for that.

However, I have to advise you that altering the database directly could have unwanted consequences and it could potentially break your WordPress installation - so make sure to backup the database often. Also, this poses a certain security risk. If I were you, I'd create a WordPress API (there may already be one, I'm not that familiar with WordPress) that will take HTTP requests and send responses as well, which your Python program would then use.